# Calculator system outprint result

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator

could somone take a look at my calculator and tell me why its stopping after asking me for numbers and what i wanna do if its add sub div or multi but doenst print out the result or do you wanna continune yes or no . Thanks in advance below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            double a,b,c;
            int choice = 0;
            a=b=c=0.0;
            while(true) {
              System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
              a = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
              b = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

              System.out.println("Enter your choice");
              System.out.println("1. Add");
              System.out.println("2. Sub");
              System.out.println("3. Mul");
              System.out.println("4. Div");

              choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

              switch(choice) {
               case 1 :
                      c = new Add().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 2 :
                      c = new Sub().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 3 :
                      c = new Div().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               case 4 :
                      c = new Mul().doMath(a,b);
                      break;
               default:
                       break;

               }

              System.out.println(c + "this is the answere");


              System.out.println("would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
              if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(sc.nextLine())) { // careful with the paranthesis 
                break;
              }
            }





}




}

interface MathOp {
public double doMath(double a, double b);
}

class Add implements MathOp{

  public double doMath(double a, double b) {
    return (a + b);
  }

}

class Sub implements MathOp{

  public double doMath(double a, double b) {
    return (a - b);
  }

}
class Div implements MathOp{

    public double doMath(double a, double b){
        return (a / b);
    }
}
class Mul implements MathOp{

    public double doMath(double a, double b){
        return (a * b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you write `sc.nextLine()` it ask for input. so you have to enter two values like
value1 then *[press enter]* then second value then *[press enter]*. 
then it will show your choice.

Do change for better input like

```
System.out.println("Enter numbers one");
              a = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
 System.out.println("Enter number two");
              b = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: tried it but thats not the problem that part is working its a bit later down after i type if 1,2,3 or 4 that it doenst print out the result

Comment: As sc.nextLine() is asking two input. you may enter `val1 val2`. you have to write `val1` then press enter and second value.

Comment: i changed for the better as u recommended but after it asks me for 
enter choise if i wanna add sub etc after that the program just crashes

Comment: exactly when i do that it crashes why?

Comment: NVm it worked thanks alot for the help BMT i cant uppvote u since im new but i would if i could'

Comment: you are welcome:) but you may accept this answer. if not possible then anyways it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

`choice` in not `Integer`. It is `int`.

I prefer BigDecimal class for mathematical issues!

[Here is link!](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/math/BigDecimal_BigInteger.shtml)

Comment: Why you not use `int i = sc.nextInt();` [Here is example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

you will not get a desired output because you for choice `3` you have made code for division but in menu it display choice `3` is meant for multiplication

this is the full code

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a,b,c;
        int choice = 0;
        a=b=c=0.0;
        while(true) {
          System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
          a = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
          b = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

          System.out.println("Enter your choice");
          System.out.println("1. Add");
          System.out.println("2. Sub");
          System.out.println("3. Div");
          System.out.println("4. Mul");

          choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

          switch(choice) {
           case 1 :
                  c = new Add().doMath(a,b);
                  break;
           case 2 :
                  c = new Sub().doMath(a,b);
                  break;
           case 3 :
                  c = new Div().doMath(a,b);
                  break;
           case 4 :
                  c = new Mul().doMath(a,b);
                  break;
           default:
                   break;

           }

          System.out.println(c + " this is the answere");


          System.out.println("would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
          if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(sc.nextLine())) { // careful with the paranthesis 
            break;
          }
        }





}




}

interface MathOp {
public double doMath(double a, double b);
}

class Add implements MathOp{

public double doMath(double a, double b) {
return (a + b);
}

}

class Sub implements MathOp{

public double doMath(double a, double b) {
return (a - b);
}

}
class Div implements MathOp{

public double doMath(double a, double b){
    return (a / b);
}
}
class Mul implements MathOp{

public double doMath(double a, double b){
    return (a * b);
}

}
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: thanks didnt notice that mistake but its not printing out the result or do you wanna continune Y/N

Comment: @user2825771 I have tested in my pc,it works perfectly well,no wrong in your code

Comment: @user2825771 check my edited answer.Copy entire code,run it and enter first number then hit enter key then enter second number and hit enter key then enter 1 then enter y